# Why is "(2.5 < 2.5 + Number.EPSILON)" false in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, precision, epsilon

I want to find values less than a certain value in the array.
I tried to use Number.EPSILON because the input value is not a definite value (eg 1.5000000000001).

I found something strange during the test:

```
>> (1.5 < 1.5 + Number.EPSILON) 
<- true 
>> (2.5 < 2.5 + Number.EPSILON)
<- false
```

Why is this?
The test environment is the Chrome browser console.

Comment: ((1.5 <1.5) + Number.EPSILON) === ((2.5 <2.5) + Number.EPSILON)  true
(1.5 <1.5 + Number.EPSILON) === (2.5 <2.5 + Number.EPSILON)  false

Comment: It is related, in some way, to precision on floating point arithmetics. I believe next read can help to understand this concept: https://www.tutorialdocs.com/article/strange-javascript-number.html. There are a lot of articles about this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Floating point numbers have a limited precision. Depending on the language and architecture, they are usually represented using 32 bits (`float`) or 64 bits (`double`, as of "double precision"). Although things become blurry in an untyped language like JavaScript, there is still an actual machine underneath all this, and this machine has to perform floating point arithmetic.

The problem is that the results of certain computations cannot be represented accurately, given the limited precision. This is explained with some examples on the [Wikipedia page about floating point artithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Addition_and_subtraction).

<sup>For people who want all the nitty-gritty details, the article about [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) is usually recommended. But seriously: Not every computer scientist needs to know all this, and I'm pretty sure that only a handful people in the world have actually *read* the whole thing....</sup>

As an overly suggestive example: Imagine you had 5 digits to store a number. When you then have an addition like

```
  10000.
+     0.00001
--------------------
= 10000.
```

the `.00001` part will basically be "truncated" because it does not fit into the 5 digits.

<sup>(That's not exactly how this works, but should get the idea across)</sup>

The actual value for `Number.EPSILON`, according to [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/EPSILON), is approximately **2.22 * 10-16**, and is the *"difference between 1 and the smallest floating point number greater than 1"*. (This is sometimes referred to as an [ULP, Unit In The Last Place](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place)).

So adding this value to 1.0 will result in a different number. But adding it to 2.5 will *not* result in a different number, because the difference between 2.5 and the smallest floating point number greater than 2.5 is *larger* than this epsilon. The epsilon is thus truncated, like the `.00001` in the example above.

---

Some languages/libraries may offer an "ulp" function that returns the difference between a given value and the next larger representable value. For example, in Java, you have

```
System.out.println(Math.ulp(1.0)); // Prints 2.220446049250313E-16
System.out.println(Math.ulp(2.5)); // Prints 4.440892098500626E-16
```

The first one obviously is what is stored in `Number.EPSILON`. The second one is the value that should yield a different value when added to 2.5. So

- `2.5 < 2.5 + 4.4408E-16` would be `false` and
- `2.5 < 2.5 + 4.4409E-16` would be `true`

Answer (score 7):

While `Number.EPSILON` itself can be represented precisely, this is no guarantee that adding values to it (or manipulating it any further at all) will result in perfect precision. In this case, `1.5 + Number.EPSILON` results in a number slightly higher than 1.5:

```js
console.log(1.5 + Number.EPSILON);
```

Which is clearly greater than 1.5. On the other hand, adding 2.5 to `Number.EPSILON` results in exactly 2.5 - the precision you were hoping for was lost during the addition process.

```js
console.log(2.5 + Number.EPSILON);
```

`2.5 < 2.5` evaluates to `false`, as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Number.EPSILON is:

> difference between 1 and the smallest floating point number greater
>   than 1

Let's say this number is 0.00000000000000000000000001 for the argument's sake.

Now,

```
1.5 < 1.5 + 0.00000000000000000000000001 === true
```

and, when the base number which you are adding this extremely small fraction grows larger, the precision calculations of the JS math evaluation finds its boundary.

```
2 < 2 + 0.00000000000000000000000001 === false
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
    ┌─────────────────────────────────────┐
    │ Number.EPSILON = 2¯⁵² ≈ 2.2 * 10¯¹⁶ │
    └─────────────────────────────────────┘

    Question 1: 2.5 < 2.5 + ε ?
                                                        2¯⁵¹
  2¹↴                                                   ⇩
    10100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000  = 2.5 (JS)
   +                                                     1 = ε
   ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
                                                        ┌┐ (01, 1 truncated )
    101000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
  = 10100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000  = 2.5 (JS)
     ╰──────────────────── 52-bit ──────────────────────╯

    ⭐️ Conclusion ❌: 2.5 === 2.5 + ε

    Question 2: 1.5 < 1.5 + ε ?
                                                        2¯⁵²
   2⁰↴                                                   ⇩
     11000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 = 1.5 (JS)
   +                                                     1 = ε
   ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
  =  11000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001 = 1.5 + ε (JS)
      ╰──────────────────── 52-bit ──────────────────────╯

    ⭐️ Conclusion ✅: 1.5 < 1.5 + ε

*/

// --------------- log ---------------

const ε = Number.EPSILON;

[
    2.5 < 2.5 + ε,      // false❗️
    1.5 < 1.5 + ε,      // true

].forEach(x => console.log(x))
```